# Найти ошибку в коде Python

Tags: python

Программа должна принимать у пользователя список чисел, и, используя контрольное значение (сумма остатков деления каждого из чисел на следующее за ним число), сравнивать полученное значение с начальным. Проблема: четвертая строка с запросом input повторяется бесконечно.

```
number_list = []
N = int(input('N: '))
for _ in range(N):
    number_list.append(input())
control_number = int(input())
exp_control_number = 0
for i in range(1, len(number_list)-2):
    exp_control_number += (number_list[i] % number_list[i + 1])//1
if control_number == exp_control_number:
    print('Список не изменился')
else:
    print('Список изменился')
```

Заранее благодарю за ответ

Comment: Почему вы решили, что в коде есть ошибка?

Comment: @dIm0n, четвертая строка с запросом input повторяется бесконечно

Comment: Укажите это в вопросе и все дальнейшие дополнения тоже там (кнопка править под вопросом). На будущее всегда приводите ошибку или проблему явно, "не работает/в коде ошибка" ничего не говорят о проблеме, а явный текст ошибки или описание неверного поведения - говорят

Comment: @dIm0n, спасибо, дополнил

Comment: Добавьте на каких входных данных это происходит, я запустил ваш код введя `5 1 2 3 4 5 6` и получил `TypeError`, а не бесконечное выполнение

Comment: @dIm0n, ответ ниже - правильный. Я неправильно понял задание. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

функция `input` всегда возвращает тип `str`. Потом вы делаете математические операции над строками, в связи с этим и получаете ошибку. Необходимо преобразовать данные в тип `int`

```
    number_list = []
    N = int(input('N: '))
    for _ in range(N):
        number_list.append(int(input()))
    control_number = int(input())
    exp_control_number = 0
    for i in range(1, len(number_list)-2):
        exp_control_number += (number_list[i] % number_list[i + 1])//1
    if control_number == exp_control_number:
        print('Список не изменился')
    else:
        print('Список изменился')
```

Comment: Даже так, программа не завершается - четвертая строка с input() повторяется бесконечно.

Comment: функция input нужна для ввода данных с клавиатуры. N = int(input('N: ')) - задается количество итераций цикла. В теле цикла вы запрашиваете ввод от пользователя. Соответственно, если ничего не вводить, программа и не завершит свою работу.

Comment: имел в виду, что append для number_list запрашивается бесконечно, вне зависимости от того, какое число вводит пользователь

Comment: запустив программу я ввожу: N: 5 клавиша enter, после чего 1 enter, 2 enter, 3 enter, 4 enter, 5 enter, 6 enter. Вывод: Список изменился

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Что-то вы путаете:

```
number_list = []
N = int(input('N: '))
for _ in range(N):
    number_list.append(int(input()))
print (number_list)

N: 5    
1    
2    
3    
4    
5
```

Результат
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Никакого бесконечного цикла.

Comment: Да, это мой косяк - не сразу понял, как вводить числа